# When I use virtualenv to create a virtual environment, why the project use it?

Tags: python, virtualenv

In my project, I use `virtualenv` created the `ENV`:

```
(ENV) bora-MBP:testDemo01 ldl$ ls
ENV             db.sqlite3      manage.py       templates       test01          testDemo01
```

You see I have an active virtual environment of the project.

In one python file of my project:

```
import six

print(six.PY3)  # print True
```

I checked the python version of my project using, there it shows it uses `Python3`.

but I cd into the `ENV/lib`, there only shows `python2.7`:

```
(ENV) bora-MBP:testDemo01 ldl$ cd ENV/lib/
(ENV) bora-MBP:lib ldl$ ls
python2.7
```

there is no `python3`, this is my first question.

My second question is, why my project will use the ENV virtual environment? where is the configuration I can check?

---

**EDIT-01**

In my first question:
I know I'm using `python3` in my project now, I can use `six.PY3` to check, or other ways, but why I create a virtual environment, there only gets `python2.7` directory under the `ENV/lib/`?

My second question:

we know my project will use the ENV environment to run program, but why? is there any default settings for my project to use this environment(`dependencies`, `packages` and so on)?  is there any configuration file for us to check(clearly point out my project testDemo01 will use the `ENV` as run environment)?

Comment: Have you definitely activate the environment?

Comment: You see the `(ENV)` before the bora-MBP

Answer (score 2):

For your first question:

Please check python version on your virtual environment using `python --version` to make sure it is python 3 or not. Check whether you have multiple versions of python using `whereis python` in the command line.

For your second question:

To make a virtual environment management process easier install virtualenvwrapper `pip install virtualenvwrapper-win`.
Then you will be able to check and change your ENV directory from 'edit the system environment variables'. Change or create 'WORKON_HOME' variable with your require path.

Based on your EDIT-01:

- It seems like you have multiple version of python installed in your machine and virtualenv is using python2.7. Please use `virtualenv -p path_of_python3 envname` to create virtualenv with python3. You can find path for all python using `whereis python` in the command line.
- You can check your dependencies using `pip freeze` inside your virtualenv.

Comment: You don't get me, I want to know why my project will use virtualenv rather than system env? what's the theory?

Comment: Your project automatically doesn't use virtualenv you need to explicitly activate it. Your code editor might be doing this for you. Are you using PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

First question, `python2.7/` under  `ENV/lib/` is because of the creation virtualenv method, if you create the ENV like this:

```
virtualenv -p python3 ./ENV
```

there should be `python3.x/` under `ENV/lib/`.

For the second question:

> is there any configuration file for us to check(clearly point out my project testDemo01 will use the ENV as run environment)?

for the source reason, you should check the `ENV/bin/active` bash file, when you active the virtual env, then the project use that yet:

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/Users/aircraft/Desktop/TestPython/Demo/venv"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

# unset PYTHONHOME if set
if ! [ -z "${PYTHONHOME+_}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME="$PYTHONHOME"
    unset PYTHONHOME
fi

if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="$PS1"
    if [ "x" != x ] ; then
        PS1="$PS1"
    else
        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`) $PS1"
    fi
    export PS1
fi
```

you see, when you execute the `active` bash, there will export the `VIRTUAL_ENV`, and add it into the `PATH`, and unset PYTHONHOME if set. This is why the project will use the virtualenv.